# SQL return count of an case insensitive query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm trying to do a query to check if a name appears in my table, I need it to be case insensitive and return if it finds a value but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
$dogqry = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM dogs WHERE UPPER(breed)=UPPER($breed_name)");

    if ($dogqry['id'] == 0){
        $errors .= "\n Breed not found. ";  
    }
```

Comment: `$breedname` needs to be in single quotes or you should use a parameterized query and mysqli_

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query is fine, and the problem is with the way in which you retrieve the result. You are trying to access a result field called `id`, while the query does not provide a column called `id`. You should either give the column a name, like this

```
$dogqry = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) cnt FROM dogs WHERE UPPER(breed)=UPPER($breed_name)");
if ($dogqry['cnt'] == 0) ... //         ^^^
```

or retrieve the result with the expression content, like this:

```
$dogqry = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM dogs WHERE UPPER(breed)=UPPER($breed_name)");
if ($dogqry['COUNT(id)'] == 0) ...
```